# Run command as bash from POSIX shell

Tags: bash, posix

I have a quick question

I have a posix shell but I need to run a bash command.

Think

```
root@home:~# sh
# /bin/bash /bin/ls
```

However, when I do that, I get

```
/bin/ls: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I'm not sure what it is. Any help? I also need to do it in one line.

Comment: `ls` is not a bash command.

Comment: ls is not a bash command, it's a binary. Just run `ls`.

Comment: ls was just an example for any old command.

Comment: "Any old command" is not a bash command. Bash commands are a bounded and finite set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the -c argument to specify a command that you want to be ran by the other shell:

" -c               Read commands from the command_string operand"

```
bash -c "ls"
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a concise answer.

Answer (score -2):

I came up with a workaround

```
echo '#!/bin/bash\--comamnd--; chmod ugo+x /tmp/script.sh; /tmp/script.sh
```

Comment: This is an unreasonably complex and fragile way to do something trivial. There is certainly a better way, but you need to be clearer about what you're actually trying to accomplish before anyone can make good suggestions.

Comment: Can you suggest a better way to phrase what I wanted to ask? For someone who's still learning, you're being awfully condescending.

Comment: I don't mean to be condescending, but I was being rather crabby -- I found your question frustrating because *I couldn't figure out what you were asking*. And I still can't. Is it really just how to run the `ls` command? If so, it's trivial: enter `ls` and press return. If there's more to it, then your example is failing to capture what you're really asking about. What's frustrating me is that *I can't tell even which of these is the case*.

Comment: More details: I'm working on reverse engineering a custom c program with a buffer overflow. I have shellcode that spawns a /bin/dash shell which can't properly utilize the ability to do "echo data > /dev/tcp/ip/port", but I can only execute a command once. So I can't open just do "bash" and then type the command in; it all has to be on one line. Bash, being a more functional shell, has this capability. The system I'm exploiting has bash installed, so I just needed a way to do what I described from a simple shell. Does that make more sense? I'm self taught on Linux and know little of internals

Comment: Ok, that does make sense -- the redirect to /dev/tcp is a bash feature, so it's really that, not the command (`echo`) you need bash for (and for that case I'd recommend none's answer). But if the target has netcat, it'd be even easier to use `echo data | nc hostname port`.